# Framerate independent acceleration/decceleration?

Tags: c++, calculus

I'm writing a particle simulator in C++.

I move particles around by adding their velocity to their position at each time step.

The value of the time step is a percentage of the current frame. So full frame time step is 1, half frame time step is .5, quarter frame time step is .25, etc. The total simulation steps is frameCount/timeStep...so the smaller the time step, the greater the total number of steps simulated.

Keeping basic movement across time steps the same is very simple. The equation is:

```
position = position + velocity * timeStep; //10 full frames later, end position is always the same
```

However, it gets too complicated for my current understanding of math once I try to change the velocity over time too. For example, if I do this:

```
velocity = velocity * .95f;
position = position + velocity * timeStep; //10 full frames later, end position dependent on time step
```

The results across different time steps are no longer the same. I know this is because if I'm increasing the total number of steps calculated by decreasing the time step, I'm also decreasing the velocity that many more times too, which will have a big impact on the final position of the particle.

How can I modify the velocity over time in such a way that I get identical results across different time steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity is change in position over time. You've correctly calculated that in your equation.

```
position = position + velocity * timeStep;
```

Acceleration is change in velocity over time. So you just use the same equation, but modify the variables accordingly. That is, change position to velocity, and velocity to acceleration. The time step stays the same.

```
velocity = velocity + acceleration * timeStep;
```

If you want to simulate friction, then what you do is multiply the velocity by some constant friction value and the time step, and subtract this from the acceleration. But this value should only be used for the frame, and not be stored in the actual acceleration value.

```
float temp_accel = acceleration - friction * velocity * timeStep;
```

Then modify your velocity according to temp_accel.

```
velocity = velocity + temp_accel * timeStep;
```

If your acceleration is zero, then you can take that out of the equation:

```
float temp_accel = -friction * velocity * timeStep;
```

Comment: Hmm, so how do I work out what the acceleration value in your function should be, from my initial (de)cceleration formula of (velocity *= .95)?

Comment: @Tyson: That is not a deceleration formula. So there's no correct way to translate it to a deceleration. I would recommend playing around with numbers until you get a value that looks and feels right.

Comment: Isn't it? It describes a change in velocity over time, namely a decrease. I guess I was hoping for a mathematical solution rather than a 'jiggle things until it works' solution.

Comment: @Tyson: I can't know the proper mathematical solution to your problem without knowing what effect you are going for.

Comment: Well in this case I'm trying to add friction to my particles to slow them over time. Right now I just multiply their velocity by x (in this case, .95) at each step of the simulation. It gives the desired effect of slowing particles down, but is not framerate independent for reasons previously listed. I want to know how I can slow their velocity in a framerate independent manner.

Comment: @Tyson: I've provided a simple equation based on the time step which will allow you to simulate friction. You can put your `0.95f` value in for friction, or try other values.

Comment: Thank you for the additional equations, although I can't seem to get them to work. For reference, in my simulation loop I do 'position += velocity;' followed by 'tempAccel = -.95 * velocity * timeStep;' followed by 'velocity += tempAccel * timeStep". However, the results are not the same across time steps. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I thought maybe multiplying tempAccel by timeStep twice (once in it's declaration and once when I add it to velocity) was the problem, but taking the second multiplication out of the last line still yields incorrect results.

Comment: @Tyson: Why have you removed timeStep from the position calculation?

Comment: Whoops...my mistake! Everything seems to work now, and I'm getting consistent results across steps. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

[I noticed users are finding this Q&A and being misled](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/187643/39518), so I wanted to post here to point out that **the accepted answer is not correct**, and does not give framerate-independent results as it claims.

We can prove this with a simple spreadsheet calculation. Set up three time series with different time steps, and use the formulas from that answer:

```
[Velocity Cell] = [Previous Velocity Cell]
                + (Accel - Frict * [Previous Velocity Cell] * [Time Step]) * [Time Step]

[Position Cell] = [Previous Position Cell] + [Velocity Cell] * [Time Step]
```

[image: Spreadsheet showing divergent trajectories]

The three sets of results will diverge noticeably after only a short time (here I'm visualizing 1.6 seconds of simulation)

This is expected, because multiplying by a time step only correctly accounts for *linear* change. It implicitly assumes that the rate of change remains constant over the interval we're simulating, so the total change over that interval is just the current rate times the duration of the interval.

As soon as the rate of change is itself allowed to change (ie. as soon as velocity can change due to acceleration like gravity or friction), then this assumption is violated. The code running on a slower/longer time step will assume velocity has just one value for the entire duration, while the code that runs at a faster/shorter time step will see multiple different values in that same interval, and naturally arrive at a different result.

[I explore this problem in more detail in this answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/185803/39518), showing how to derive equations that account for the rate of change shifting during the simulated interval, but here's the TL;DR:

If you want framerate-independent integration with a **constant acceleration**, use:

```
position += velocity * timeStep + 0.5 * acceleration * timeStep * timeStep;
velocity += acceleration * timeStep;
```

If you want framerate-independent integration with **multiplicative drag**, use:

```
newVelocity = velocity * pow(fractionRemainingAfterOneSecond, timeStep);

position += (newVelocity - velocity) / naturalLog(fractionRemainingAfterOneSecond);

velocity = newVelocity;
```

If you want framerate-independent integration with both acceleration and drag... you can't get it (sorry). We don't have a closed-form solution to the integral

[image: Nasty integral]

And even the two solutions I gave above as supposedly framerate-independent are only truly so if you have infinite-precision real numbers. In actual code, you'll get rounding errors at each step, and running the same simulation with different time steps will cause the rounding errors to pile up in different places. But they will be significantly more robust than what's presented in the accepted answer.

---

For completeness, here's a comparison showing trajectories simulated using the framerate-independent formulas above, stepped at 60 FPS and 10 FPS. I've also included an analytical solution that doesn't use accumulated deltas at all, to show that not only do the simulations with different timesteps agree with one another, they also agree with the ground truth (up to rounding errors).

[image: Acceleration Graph]

[image: Braking Graph]

Comment: (at least for my application) the accepted answer does the job. I've tried it out by printing the delta position each frame. The server which runs at half the fps of the client does exactly double the delta position of the client. However, with your presented formula (first one) it's not the exactly double the delta position of the client.

Comment: The thrust of this answer is that double the delta position of the client is *not correct* when the object is accelerating. We'd expect the delta to double when the interval doubles when the object is moving with a constant velocity. If the object is decelerating, then over twice the interval it should travel somewhat less than twice the distance (because it's moving slower during the second half). If the object is accelerating, it should travel somewhat more than twice the distance (because it's moving faster during the second half). What you need to compare are the absolute positions.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good, but I want to emphasize that you can never be *completely* independent of the simulation's step size.

The equations of motion (which give us position and velocity at some point in time) are integrals.  Simulations approximate integration by doing sums over small steps.  But because those steps are finite rather than infinitesimal, there's always error.  The smaller you can make the steps, the more you can reduce the error.

For video games and UI animations, time steps on the order of the frame rate, say 10-100 steps per second, are usually sufficient to keep the error small enough that it has no adverse effect on the appearance of the animation or the playability of a game.

But if you run the same simulation at both 10 and 100 steps per second, you can get different results because the latter is a better approximation than the former.

Making the steps smaller also increases the amount of computation.  Sometimes, you don't have enough horsepower to use steps small enough to keep the error within reason.  For these circumstances, there are numerical integrators, which give better approximations than repeated sums.  Probably the best known numerical integrator is [Runge-Kutta (RK4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge.E2.80.93Kutta_method).  If you find that you have to set your `timeStep` impractically small, try using RK4.